# Access 2010 Web Database How to extract a particular column from combo box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a web database in access 2010

I have a combo box on which I have set the number of columns = 2

I have also set the query to populate the combo box to

select id, value from table1

Now I have a second combo box for which I want to write query like

select id, value, lookup from table2 where table2.lookup = [Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]

but this doesn't work because its a multi column combo

I also tried

```
select id, value, lookup from table2 where table2.lookup = [Forms]![Form1]![Combo1].Column(1)
```

but this is invalid syntax

Comment: See if this helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/339a1dfe-aa03-41e1-bdc4-e8798a547053/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access 2010 - Web Databases - Create cascading combo boxes in one form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325143/access-2010-web-databases-create-cascading-combo-boxes-in-one-form)

Comment: No not duplicate.

The above 2 links are on how to create cascading boxes. This question is about how to extract ID and value from a multi column combo box.

Comment: It works for me with a webform. The value of a combo is always the value of the bound column and unless you have changed it, the bound column will be 1, making the value of the combo the ID. Try building your query in the query design window and testing. You can refer to the column property, but not in a query.